# ¿Cómo imprimir textos diferentes en base a llamada de función recursiva?

Tags: c, recursión

Necesito resolver el siguiente problema de manera recursiva.

"*Escriba en C una función recursiva llamada `maquina_sueno` que recibe como parámetro el nivel del sueño a acceder y muestra por pantalla el mensaje que muestra la máquina al entrar a ese nivel.*"

Ejemplo:

```
maquina_sueno(4);
```

Debe imprimir:

```
Entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno
```

¿Como puedo hacer que el texto "*Entrando en el sueno*" se imprima solo una vez, independiente del número que se recibe como parámetro?

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
void maquina_sueno(int n) {
  if (n == 1) {
     printf("Entrando en el sueno");
  } else {  
     printf(" del sueno "); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo ambigua, podrías adjuntar el código con el que trabajas para ayudarnos a entenderla.

Comment: void maquina_sueno(int n){
    if(n==1){
        printf("Entrando en el sueno");
    }else{
        printf(" del sueno ");
    }
}

El problema es que la primera linea se imprime al final, como podria imprimirla al inicio?

Answer (score 3):

La función que propones en tu pregunta, no cumple con el concepto clave de recursividad, por lo que te recomiendo que estudies un poco más al respecto, pero volviendo a tu problema:

> Creo que he entendido tu problema, te exige resolverlo de manera recursiva, por lo que ciclos no son una opción, así que he diseñado esta solución:

```
void maquina(int num, int princ) {
  if (princ) 
    printf("Entrando en el sueno");

  if (num) {
    printf(" del sueno");
    maquina(num - 1, 0);
  }
}
```

Al llamar a `maquina(10, 1)` obtienes por resultado:

```
Entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno
```

Que supongo es lo que necesitas.

### Desglosando el código:

- La firma o signature del metodo `maquina` acepta dos parámetros y la llamamos por primera vez de la siguiente manera:

  ```
  #include ... // Aqui va stdio...
  int main(void) {
    maquina(10, 1); // El 1 en la primera llamada, para imprimir "Entrando en el sueno"...
  }
  ```
- El segundo parámetro llamado `princ`, determina si es la primera llamada y dentro de la función se comprueba:

  ```
  if (princ)
      printf("Entrando en el sueno");
  ```
- Luego de ello, se verifíca si el número es distinto de cero y se llama de nuevo a la función:

  ```
  if (num) {
    printf(" del sueno"); // Imprime "del sueno"
    maquina(num - 1, 0);  // Atento al cero en el segundo argumento.
  }
  ```

Así, si en su proxima llamada, `num - 1` es igual a cero, no se imprime nada y termina la recursión.

### EDIT:

Un segundo enfoque, demanda dos parametros de igual forma, pero es igual de valida:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void maquina_tail(int);

void maquina(int num) {
  printf("entrando en el sueno");
  maquina_tail(num);
}

void maquina_tail(int num) {  
  if (num) {
    printf(" del sueno");
    maquina_tail(num - 1);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  maquina(10);
}
```

Esta segunda opcion es llamada *[Tail Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)*, al ejecutar `maquina(10)` obtienes el siguiente resultado:

```
entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno
```

Comment: Me has fallado en la respuesta, colega :-P   **Hay por lo menos 2 formas** de hacer la llamada recursiva con 1 solo argumento. A ver si se reabre ... ( y cada forma con varias variantes jeje Como mínimo, 6 formas en total ).

Comment: No que el objetivo era enseñarle el concepto de _recursión_? xD

Comment: ¡¡ Anda ya !! El objetivo es *flipar* a la peña XDD thx por el +1 ;-) Te lo devuelvo ;-)

Comment: ¡Jajajaja! Bueno, bueno, para la proxima le doy todas las que se me ocurran sin explicación alguna :P

Answer (score 2):

Para cumplir con la interfaz que propones puedes hacer algo tal que:

```
void maquina_sueno(int n) {
  if( n <= 1 )
    printf("Entrando en el sueno");
  else
  {
    maquina_sueno(n-1);
    printf(" del sueno");
  }
}
```

Explicación:

`maquina_sueno(n)` provoca una llamada recursiva hasta `maquina_sueno(1)`. En ese momento se imprime el mensaje inicial `"Entrando en el sueno"`. Después se va abandonando la recursividad y, en cada uno de estos pasos, se va imprimiendo la coletilla `"del sueno"`

Answer (score 1):

Vale, me pasé en el comentario a @NaCl. Una de las variantes es a su vez variante de otra, así que, al final, lo dejamos en 4 :-/

Tienes, como mínimo, **2** formas de hacerlo. Cada una de ellas, a su vez, con como mínimo **2** variantes:

## Usa variables auxiliares.

**No** es necesario que las pases como argumentos.

#### 1 Externas a la función `maquina_sueno( )`.

Simplemente, las declaras *fuera* de cualquier función, para que sean *variables globales*.

#### 2 Internas a la función.

Declaras la variables auxiliar **dentro** de la función, pero usando `static`.

## Juega con el argumento.

Lo que importa es **lo que quieres indicar**, no **como lo inidicas**.

#### 3 Juega con los bits.

Estas usando un argumento numérico. Los números **tienen** bits individuales, que puedes usar.

#### 4 Conviértelo en negativo, para indicar que ya has pasado por ahí.

Lo más fácil en tu caso.

Código de ejemplo, con las 4 posibles formas de hacerlo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int firstCall = 1;

void maquina1( int l ) {
  if( l ) {
    if( firstCall ) {
      firstCall = 0;
      printf( "entrando en el sueno" );
    } else {
      printf( " del sueno" );
    }
    maquina1( --l );
  } else {
    printf( "\n" );
    firstCall = 0;
  }
}

void maquina2( int l ) {
  static int aFirstCall = 1;

  if( l ) {
    if( aFirstCall ) {
      aFirstCall = 0;
      printf( "entrando en el sueno" );
    } else {
      printf( " del sueno" );
    }
    maquina2( --l );
  } else {
    printf( "\n" );
    aFirstCall = 0;
  }
}
void maquina3( unsigned l ) {
  int bit = l & ( 1 << 31 ); // Obtenemos el bit.

  l ^= ( 1 << 31 ); // Lo quitamos.

  if( l ) {
    if( !bit ) {
      printf( "entrando en el sueno" );
    } else {
      printf( " del sueno" );
    }
    --l;
    l |= ( 1 << 31 ); // Volvemos a poner el bit.
    maquina3( l );
  } else {
    printf( "\n" );
  }
}

void maquina4( int l ) {
  if( l ) {
    if( l > 0 ) {
      printf( "entrando en el sueno" );
      l *= -1;
    } else {
      printf( " del sueno" );
    }
    maquina4( ++l );
  } else {
    printf( "\n" );
  }
}


int main( void )  {
  maquina1( 3 );
  maquina2( 4 );
  maquina3( 5 );
  maquina4( 6 );
  return 0;
}
```

Lo anterior genera la siguiente salida:

> `entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno`
> `entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno`
> `entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno`
> `entrando en el sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno del sueno`

Comment: Tenga su +10, Jajaja.

Answer (score 1):

no necesitas el else, cuando llegue a n==1, se regresará a cada llamada a imprimir la linea "del sueno"

```
void maquina_sueno(int n) {

  if (n == 1)
  {
     printf("Entrando en el sueno");
     return;
  }   

  maquina_sueno(n-1)
  printf(" del sueno "); 

}
```